# Get all results from a repo on the GitHub API that does not give a value for 'Link'?

Tags: pagination, request, response, github-api, access-control

I'm trying to get all of the pull requests for a given repo. The GitHub API paginates results such that you cannot get all the results at once. In the documentation, they say that getting all of the results will require knowing how many pages there are. They say you can learn how many pages there are by getting the Link response header, which you should be able to get with `curl -I https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails`, for instance. But, while that works for the rails repository, it does not work for the repo that I need: /lodash/lodash. When I run the same command with lodash, I get:

`curl -I https://api.github.com/repos/lodash/lodash/pulls`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-
Limit,...
...
```

In other words, Link is an Access-Control-Expose-Header for the lodash repository. I haven't been able to find any information on how to get it, given that.
So I believe the crux of my question is "How do I get an Access-Control-Expose-Header?" but I wanted to provide context in case there is another way of getting all pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

As for today, there is no opened pull request for repository [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/pulls), so you will have no result.

From [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests), default `state` is `open` when you retrieve pull requests :

> Either open, closed, or all to filter by state. Default: open

Applying a filter that gives more pages will give you the `Link` header :

```
curl -I https://api.github.com/repos/lodash/lodash/pulls?state=all
```